# Merging the keys inside an object with checking two dimensional arary

Tags: javascript

How to merge the keys in the array into a single key with using the separator, if value is null don't take it

```
let keysToBeMerged = [['note', 'status', seperator: ' ,'], ['group', 'level', seperator: ' ()']];
let data = [
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "key": "area",
        "value": null
      },
      {
        "key": "terminal",
        "value": null
      },
      {
        "key": "note",
        "value": "Some key notes"
      },
      {
        "key": "status",
        "value": "Enabled"
      },
      {
        "key": "group",
        "value": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "key": "level",
        "value": null
      }
    ],
    "name": "test 1",
    "number": "123456127890",
    "id": "yqweyqweu213"
  },
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "key": "area",
        "value": "Delhi"
      },
      {
        "key": "terminal",
        "value": null
      },
      {
        "key": "note",
        "value": "Some key orginal notes"
      },
      {
        "key": "status",
        "value": "Disabled"
      },
      {
        "key": "group",
        "value": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "key": "level",
        "value": "High"
      }
    ],
    "name": "test 2",
    "number": "173276123612",
    "id": "uqweyewueyyuqwe"
  },
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "key": "area",
        "value": "Mumbai"
      },
      {
        "key": "terminal",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "key": "note",
        "value": "Some key orginal sample notes"
      },
      {
        "key": "status",
        "value": "Enabled"
      },
      {
        "key": "group",
        "value": "Low"
      },
      {
        "key": "level",
        "value": null
      }
    ],
    "name": "test 3",
    "number": "128737812381723",
    "id": "kasjdashdkaskjd"
  }
]
```

I have a collection called keysToBeMerged, I need to find the key from the he fields collection and need to merge some keys into a single key with merged values with using the separator.

I tried with below snippet

```
 data.map(o => {
    let key = []
    let value = []
    o.fields.forEach(f => {
      keysToBeMerged.forEach(kColl => {
            if(kColl.includes(f.key)){
              key.push(f.key)
              value.push(f.value)
            }
          })
          console.log(key.join(""))
          console.log(value.join(""))
        })
  return o
  })
```

The expected result is shown below:

```
let expectedResult = [
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "key": "area",
        "value": null
      },
      {
        "key": "terminal",
        "value": null
      },
      {
        "key": "note|status",
        "value": "Some key notes, Enabled"
      },
      {
        "key": "group|level",
        "value": "Medium"
      }
    ],
    "name": "test 1",
    "number": "123456127890",
    "id": "yqweyqweu213"
  },
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "key": "area",
        "value": "Delhi"
      },
      {
        "key": "terminal",
        "value": null
      },
      {
        "key": "note|status",
        "value": "Some key orginal notes, Disabled"
      },
      {
        "key": "group|level",
        "value": "Medium (High)"
      },
    ],
    "name": "test 2",
    "number": "173276123612",
    "id": "uqweyewueyyuqwe"
  },
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "key": "area",
        "value": "Mumbai"
      },
      {
        "key": "terminal",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "key": "note|status",
        "value": "Some key orginal sample notes, Enabled"
      },
      {
        "key": "group|level",
        "value": "Low"
      },
    ],
    "name": "test 3",
    "number": "128737812381723",
    "id": "kasjdashdkaskjd"
  }
]
```

Comment: The separator logic is not consistent. `Some key notes, Enabled` is fine. But `Medium (High)` is not exactly *joining* with a separator. We'll have to manually check for `()` which kind of defeats the purpose of having a `keysToBeMerged` array

Comment: no thats the problem i was thinking. But for now its brackets and comma

Comment: @MaheerAli fine.

Comment: @adiga but i think then we need to check manually for that specific seperator

Comment: `keysToBeMerged` has invalid syntax, please fix it so we are sure about the structure before trying to answer this. You could've added to your previous question instead of posting again. The solution is almost the same as the previous accepted answer. But instead of map() and sort(), you're going to map() and `reduce()` now so the fields array becomes smaller according to some rules. Small tip: the accumulator of `.reduce()` can be anything, like an object containing the merged fields array you're building and the current element you're trying to find the other half for.

Comment: @adiga or instead of having a seperator key, shall we make an array like [" " , ","] and [" ", "(" , ")"] does it help anyway

Comment: @Shilly i was trying to get a solution for this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56339879/building-a-different-array-structure-from-array-of-objects-and-keys-based-on-so . But i dont know whether the way i am following is a good approach

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS This is going to be a very messy reduction anyway due to the requirements, so there's no 'good approach' imvho. I assume you have no control, over how `data` looks? Else I would prefer a simpler data format. What is going to use a string like `"note|status"` to produce anything meaningful? Your 3 questions together smell like an x/y problem. Are you generating an array to turn into a HTML template? If so, can you change that template?

Comment: yes. i am trying to render a component in jsx where the fields will be showing as key and value. The other flattened properties will be used without key. It will be showing the value directly

the name and number will be joined together like test1(1236712367), id is used for binding and the remaining fields collection will be rendered as an key value pair

Comment: You have now 4 almost identical questions about the same data structure within 24 hours. Instead of posting a question for each individual change you need to make to the array, please post one full explanation why you need the array to be updated in all these weird ways. AS long as we do not know what you're tryign to do, there's a big chance our answers won't fit your requirements and you'll post a 4th almost identical question.

Comment: can you  check out this question, and let me know what you have not understood https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56339879/building-a-different-array-structure-from-array-of-objects-and-keys-based-on-so

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS In that case, you can use multiple arrays and variables to create the template, you  re not forced to put everything inside the same array of objects. Slightly better template code will save you from all these inline transformations. Please include the template inside this question, since i have a hunch you're going to be able to throw away all these map() and filter() and sort() and just use the `results` and `fields` arrays separately. The fields array only matters for the JSX generating HTML. it does NOT belong inside the raw data of `results`.

Comment: updated with the jsx template https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56339879/building-a-different-array-structure-from-array-of-objects-and-keys-based-on-so.

Comment: @Shilly did you checked it, any doubts

Comment: Will look further when I have time. Your current template is very simple, so I have to combine the questions from the other questions as well, like the updated labels, to provide a workable answer. And SO isn't my job, so can't promise I'll post my answer this evening. Worst case tomorrow somewhere.  One question: Are all fields always present on each collection item? If so, we could just write all the label text already in the template instead of trying to update the collection.

Comment: I think if you check this you will be able to understand the flow. I have done mostly but the problem is I am not able to merge two keys. I will update the snippet what I have achieved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56339879/building-a-different-array-structure-from-array-of-objects-and-keys-based-on-so. So you can answer on that question I will delete this one